# How to write xpath for a field and validate the fields

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a requirement to verify field name and values. My code looks like

```
<div class="line info">
            <div class="unit labelInfo TextMdB">
                Reference #:
            </div>
            <div class="unit lastUnit">
               701
            </div>
        </div>      

    </div>

<div class="line info">
                <div class="unit labelInfo TextMdB">
                    Registered Date:
                </div>
                <div class="unit lastUnit">
                    05/05/2020
                </div>
            </div>
```

I gave my xpath as
 "//div[@class='unit lastUnit']//preceding-sibling::div[@class='unit labelInfo TextMdB' and contains(text(),'Reference #:')]".

With this xpath I am able to reach "reference#" field . But how to verify reference # field is displaying the value (in this case 701) .

Appreciate your response.
Thanks

Comment: which coding language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first reach the `Reference #` text by using its text in the xpath and then you can use `following-sibling` to fetch the `div` tag and then use `getText()`(java) / `text` (python) method to get `701`.

*(Edited answer after OP's comment)*
If you want to check if the element is displayed on the page or not then you can fetch its list and check if the size of that list is greater than 0 or not.

You can do it like:

In Java:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='line info']//div[contains(text(),'Reference #')]//following-sibling::div"));
if(elementList.size()>0){
    // Element is present on the UI
    // Finding its text
    String text = elementList.get(0).getText();
}
```

In python:

```
elementList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='line info']//div[contains(text(),'Reference #')]//following-sibling::div")
if (elementList.len>0):
    # Element is present
    # Printing its text
    print(elementList[0].text)
```

Comment: Thanks you for the response. But I want to verify whether 701 is displaying or not.

Comment: @siri in that case you can fetch the list of the element and then check if the size of that element is greater than zero or not. I have edited the answer, you can check the latest answer.